# Кодирование инструкций x86, 32-битные смещения - со знаком или без?

Tags: ассемблер, x86

Я всегда думал, что полное смещение (непосредственно в коде) задаётся так же, как и короткое (8-битное) - как число со знаком. Но недавно наткнулся на такую статью: http://altcode.ru/assembler/ssm/asm26.php
Небольшой отрывок:

> рассматривая вычисление адреса точки перехода, следует иметь в виду
>   явление оборачивания, суть которого можно кратко выразить такими
>   соотношениями:
>
> FFFFh+0001h=0000h
>
> 0000h-0001h=FFFFh
>
> Если последовательно увеличивать содержимое какого-либо регистра или
>   ячейки памяти, то, достигнув верхнего возможного предела FFFFh, число
>   "перевалит" через эту границу, станет равным нулю и продолжит
>   нарастать в области малых положительных чисел (1, 2, 3, и т.д.) <...>
>   **Таким образом, при вычислении адреса точки перехода смещение следует считать числом без знака, но при этом учитывать явление оборачивания**

Статья о 16-битных процессорах. После того как я это прочитал, я задался вопросом о смещениях в 32-битном режиме, полистал документацию от Intel и AMD, гуглил, но так и не смог найти прямой ответ. Решил проверить на практике, посмотрел в дизассемблере как кодируется jmp near при переходе назад, при EIP=4250F0 и метке на 424FF0 (смещение метки: -256) получилось:

```
E9 00FFFFFF
```

Переставив байты в правильном порядке получается FFFFFF00, т.е. как раз -256. Получается, что смещение задаётся как число со знаком...

Вопросы у меня такие:

1) Всегда ли 32-битные смещения (непосредственно заданные в коде) задаются как число со знаком? Или всё-таки есть случаи, когда без знака?

2) Прав ли автор статьи, что в 16-битном режиме смещения задаются как беззнаковые, или это чушь какая-то?

3) Где всё-таки можно об этом почитать? В документации ("Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual" и "AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual") никак не могу ничего на эту тему найти, там везде указывается только размер (1,2,4 байта).

Answer (score 2):

Я всё-таки нашёл описание непосредственно заданных смещений. Ответы такие:

1) JMP NEAR - использует относительное (относительно значения EIP) смещение, которое представлено как число со знаком.

JMP FAR - использует абсолютное смещение, которое представлено как число без знака.

2) В статье чушь (отчасти), абсолютное смещение - это конкретный адрес, никакого "явления оборачивания" там нет.

3) Как оказалось, это описано не в разделе "Instruction format" (где я искал), а в описании самой инструкции JMP.